# How to Round off in money related

Tags: c#, rounding

I am working on Money round off but I don't know to do it. so, How can I round off these
example - **22.32** to **20.00** OR **156.32** to **150.00** OR **23556.00** to **23550.00**

I am implementing this code...

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double a = 22.58;
            //double b = Math.Round(a, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);//?
            //double b = Math.Floor(a + .5);//?
            Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why is 23556.00 rounded to 23550.00? Everywhere else you're rounding to the nearest integer... Additionally, you should use `decimal` rather than `double` for currency values.

Comment: What are your criterias? 1sf? 3dp? Also, for money, use decimal.

Comment: Convert to int, divide by ten, then multiply by ten? That will do the rounding you describe in your example, but I doubt that's what you want.

Comment: i want to show the money in rounded figures only...

Comment: I was trying to do so i was unable to do so.... so what i tried in the programming i posted in my question. my intention is to convert 22.3 to 20.0

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        decimal a = 22.58m;

        decimal rounded = Math.Floor(a / 10m) * 10m;

        Console.WriteLine("{0:0.00}", rounded);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```